# EAPI, PAPI, SAPI. Which layer should caching be applied to?

Tags: api, caching, sapi

When we are thinking to apply API caching for a general system with 3-layer API architecture (ClientApp --> EAPI --> PAPI --> SAPI --> Backend system). Is that any general practice about which API layer the API caching should be applied to? 
Shall we apply to the EAPI layer which is closest to the user edge ClientAPP?
or
Shall we apply to the SAPI layer which is closest to the source of backend system?

Comment: Interestingly neither the SO tag ‘sapi’ or ‘papi’ is relevant in the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

**API** caching apply to the **SAPI** layer which is closest to the source of backend system.